# Four digit-number that cannot contain sequence $45$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

I keep coming up with the result $8720$ for this, but it's not correct.

I calculate like this:

Total number of four-digit numbers: $9000$

Combinations beginning with $45$ ($45xx$): $100$

Combinations with $45$ in the middle ($x45x$): $90$

Combinations with $45$ at the end ($xx45$): $90$

So: $9000-100-90-90=8720$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Well, what about $4545$?

Comment: As lulu mentioned, you have double counted $4545$ when counting the number of combinations with $45.$ You simply have to add it back (remember, you subtracted extra).

Comment: You were right, it was 8721, should have added one. Thank you! (Computer corrected, that was how I knew but didn't have the answer)